# Download .mp3 file instead of playing them in firefox or chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on wordpress website and i want to save mp3 file in my pc. But when i click on link, it open in same/new tab and start playing. But i wanna that whenever user click on download button then mp3 will start downloading. Can anyone help me how can I download an audio file (mp3) from a link and save it to my pc.

```html
<td data-th="Download Sound"><a href="https://www.example.com/meditation.mp3"><img title="Download MP3" src="https://i.imgur.com/jUu9ky3.png" alt="Download MP3" width="200" height="60" /></a></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `a` tag a `download` property

```
       <td data-th="Download Sound">
           <a href="https://www.example.com/meditation.mp3" download="meditation.mp3">
              <img title="Download MP3" src="https://i.imgur.com/jUu9ky3.png" alt="Download MP3" width="200" height="60" />
          </a>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it worked for me

`<a href="filepath" download> Download link </a>`